# How do I set up a function that displays a set vector only when 3 is entered?

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that creates a vector that counts up and back based on the number given `c(1:n, (n-1):1)`. When `3` is entered, however, I want the vector to display as `1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3` instead of `1,2,3,2,1`. I have tried using `if(n==3)`, but I get an error when I try to run it that says *"n cannot be found"*, but I can't quite understand why. Any help is very much appreciated! Here is what I have tried:

```
vector<-function(n)
  c(1:n, (n-1):1)
  if(n==3)
    c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3))
```

Comment: you should use curly brackets `{ ... }` behind your function `vector <- function(n)` if the number of expressions in function is more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one it's working :

```
vector<-function(n)
{
   if(n==3)
      rep(1:3, each=3)
   else
      c(1:n, (n-1):1)
}
```

Comment: This gives c(1, 0, 1) if n=1.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck you can add an another "if" to handle that case.

Answer (score 6):

### Problems

There are several problems with the code in the question:

- the { ... } are missing from the function so only the first line after the `function` line would actually be regarded as part of the function.
- a function returns the value of the last statement executed and the last statement executed in the question is the `if` or the body of the `if` so the `c(1:n, (n-1):1)` statement is computed but can never be returned.
- also if n=1 then `c(1:n, (n-1):1)` gives 1,0,1 which is not likely what you want.
- `c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3))` is not wrong in terms of the result it gives but `rep` can be used in a more compact manner.
- normally x:y is not used in programming because if y < x then it unexpectedly gives values descending from x to y.  In this case the `if` statements excluse such a possibility but you might want to replace the colon with the appropriate `seq` anyways.  The *Alternatives to Second Leg in Last if* section below provides such an alternative.

### Solution

Instead try this. It first checks if n is less than 1 and if so returns a zero length vector; otherwise, the remaining `if` is run with two legs, one leg for the n = 1 or n = 3 case and one leg for the remaining cases.

(If you are willing to only have this work for n > 0 then we could omit the first `if`.  If you are willing to only have this work n > 1 then we could omit the n==1 part of the condition in the last `if` too.)

```
myfun <- function(n) {
  if (n < 1) integer(0)
  else if (n == 1 || n == 3) rep(1:n, each = n)
  else c(1:n, (n-1):1)
}
```

giving:

```
myfun(-1)
## integer(0)

myfun(0)
## integer(0)

myfun(1)
## [1] 1

myfun(2)
## [1] 1 2 1

myfun(3)
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3

myfun(4)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
```

### Alternatives for first leg of last if

Here are some alternatives for the first leg, i.e. for `n <- 3`.

```
rep(1:n, each = n)
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3

c(outer(rep(1, n), 1:n))
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3

c(col(diag(n)))
## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

### Alternatives for second leg of last if

and here are some alternatives for the second leg.  The first assumes n > 1 and the others assume n > 0.  In the code in the Solution section we handle n=1 in the n=3 leg so any of the following could be used.  As the first alternative below does not handle n=1 it relies on the fact that the first leg of the last `if` handles n=1; however, the remaining alternatives below can handle n=1 correctly so they could be used even if we only have the first leg handle n=3.

```
c(1:n, (n-1):1)  # only works for n > 1

c(seq_len(n), rev(seq_len(n-1)))

pmin(seq(2*n - 1), seq(2*n-1, 1))

n - abs((n-1):-(n-1))
```

Comment: Not sure why this got a dv.  It answers the question.  I'd be more inclined to dv the continued use of `c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3))` since the use of `rep` is not well understood.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you ran the function with as one-liner and worked, then you added the conditional statement.

Try this

```
vector<-function(n){
  m <- c(1:n, (n-1):1) 
  if(n==3) m<- c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3))
  m
}
```

Another way to do it

```
Vector2 <- function(n){
  if(n == 3 ){
    return(c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3)))
  } else{
    return(c(1:n, (n-1):1) )
  }
}
```